# Strip a framework inside a static library if not needed

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, static-libraries, facebook-ios-sdk

I have an iOS static library which uses a couple of frameworks, e.g. FacebookSDK. Some of the apps that use my library need that SDK, and some don't. I'm trying to make Xcode strip Facebook SDK when building any project that does't need it. Here's what I've done:

- Set Dead Code Stripping to YES in both the library and the client app project
- Added the `-dead_strip` linker flag to both projects
- Made FacebookSDK an optional framework in the client app
- Made sure I don't create any Facebook objects in my app (by running grep on the code among other things).

And yet FacebookSDK keeps get rolled into the app binary.  The command `nm MyApp.app/MyApp  | grep FB` returns a whole bunch of Facebook symbols.

But why is Facebook getting linked? And how to avoid it?

Comment: "Made sure I don't create any Facebook objects in my app (by running Instruments and examining the created objects. Also by staring at the code for a long time.)" - did you also try grepping your source files for FB stuff?

Comment: @auspicious99 yes. I'll do it again tomorrow, just to be sure.

Comment: Yes, I did use grep to ensure I don't use any Facebook classes in my app.